# Can't push to protected branch in GitHub Action

Tags: github-actions

I have a GitHub action that I have created in order to create a new version and publish it for our JS repo.  It looks similar to this

```
steps:
  # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2

  - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
    with:
      node-version: 12.18.3
      registry-url: https://npm.pkg.github.com/
      scope: '<redacted>'

  - name: Install Dependencies
    run: npm ci

  - name: Build
    run: npm run build

  - name: Bump Version & Push
    run: |
      git config --local user.email "<redacted>"
      git config --local user.name "<redacted>"
      npm version patch
      git push https://${{ secrets.KEY }}@github.com/<redacted> HEAD:master --follow-tags
```

The KEY that I am using is a person access token I created from my account.  I have set the repo so that I have push access to the master branch.  When I try the push command from my machine with the access token it works without an issue.  However every time I see this in the GitHub Action

```
remote: error: GH006: Protected branch update failed for refs/heads/master.        
remote: error: You're not authorized to push to this branch. Visit https://docs.github.com/articles/about-protected-branches/ for more information.
```

I have been racking my brain trying to figure this out and I'm out to ideas.  If I remove the branch protection this action works fine.

Comment: What permissions do you need on the token to have push access on a blocked branch?

Comment: If your user has admin access, the `repo` permissions should be enough. @peterevans's answer below did fix my issue.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think this is because of how authentication is persisted by [`actions/checkout`](https://github.com/actions/checkout). It's stored in an `extraheader` config option which takes precedence over the credentials you are setting manually.

Try not persisting the auth:

```
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    with:
      persist-credentials: false
```

Or alternatively:

```
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    with:
      token: ${{ secrets.KEY }}
```

I know this because I've had my [own issue](https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/162) with overriding this config option in the past.

Comment: this solution saved us hours of debugging

Comment: Thank you! I've been working on this for a whole day and this was the solution.